# Do shared documents point to SharePoint or open the documents directly?

Tags: document-set

I have two questions concerning shared documents from SharePoint 2013.

1. Do shared documents open the document within the software application or direct the receiver to SharePoint?
2. Can I share a document to myself? I was told since I already have access to the document SharePoint won't allow me to share it with myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On 1, I believe you are referring to the email that gets sent when a document is shared.  The email contains a link to the document within SharePoint so the user's browser opens SharePoint first before a determination is made whether to open in a client application, show in the browser, or download the file.

On 2, yes you can share a file with yourself even if you have access but you should be aware that this results in unique permissions being applied to that one document.  This can become an administrative headache if everyone does it.  If you already have access, then don't share with yourself, instead just get the link to the file.